# Can someone explain why odd moments vanish for centered, symmetric-about-0 random variables?

Tags: probability, random, symmetry

(as in the title).  I'm particularly interested in whether there's an intuitive way to understand this.  I've done a handful of calculations with moments, but the concept is still a bit new to me.

Comment: Can you explain a little about what "intuitive" means to you?  Personally, I don't find higher *moments* to be terribly intuitive (the first and second moments are relatively intuitive to me, and I can wrap my head around the third moment---after that, my intuition fails).  Before attempting to give intuition about why certain moments vanish, it would be helpful if you could add some details about what kind of intuition you are after, and how that relates to your intuition about what moments actually *are*.

Comment: For what it is worth, my "intuition" is pretty formal:  a moment is an integral of the form $\int x^k f(x)$.  If $f$ is symmetric about zero, then $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ (that is, $f$ is an even function).  But then $x^k f(x)$ is even when $k$ is even, and odd when $k$ is odd.  The integral of an odd function over the real line vanishes, hence the odd moments vanish.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : I think I was hoping that moments had some kind of "meaning" beyond their exact definition, but it sounds like after the 1st (average) and maybe 2nd (related to variance), there's not much more to be said.  I had figured that if all odd moments described some type of useful probabilistic quantity/quantities, then there would be some extra understanding behind the phrase "odd moments vanish".  Perhaps this was a bit wishful though.  Thanks for your second post; that was helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you're hoping for some sort of useful interpretation of this fact, but I don't know that there is one... I think there are useful interpretations of the *central moments*, i.e. $\mathbb E[(X - \mu)^k]$ including for higher powers of $k$, but I'm not sure that that I have ever seen much in the way of meaningful interpretations for the *raw moments* $\mathbb E[X^k]$ beyond $k = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$, then $-X^n = (-X)^n$ has the same distribution as $X^n$. Then $E[X^n] = E[-X^n] = -E[X^n]$ so...

Answer (score 2):

My intuition about this is in two parts. First, because of the symmetry about $0$, the average of your random variable (the first moment) is $0$. If it were positive, then by symmetry it should be negative, and vice versa.

Second, what about higher odd moments, $E(X^k)$? Well, $X^k$ has the same symmetry property as $X$. Reversing the sign of $X$ also reverses the sign of $X^k$. So the previous paragraph applies to the random variable $X^k$ and shows that its expectation is also $0$.

(Note: All this is under the assumption that the moments exist.)

Comment: I'm not understanding the sentence: "If it were positive, then by symmetry it should be negative, and vice versa."  Do you mean if the average were positive?  I'm just not sure what the 'it' is referring to.

Comment: Yes, "it" in that sentence means the average.

Comment: I'm still not understanding the sentence though -- if the average is positive why should it also be negative?  Wouldn't it have to be zero then?  Or is that what you're trying to say with the phrase "by symmetry"?

Comment: Imagine the real line drawn (as usual) with negative numbers to the left and positive ones to the right. Suppose, toward a contradiction, that the expectation of $X$ is positive (so on the right). Now look at the situation in a mirror, switching right and left. The random variable is unchanged (by symmetry) but its expectation is now on the left. A changed expectation for an unchanged random variable is contradictory. So the expectation of $X$ cannot be positive. By an analogous argument, it can't be negative. So it must be zero (assuming it exists).

Comment: Ok -- I see what you're saying.